# Invalid factory configuration javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan

When i use the combination of XSLT 1.0 and saxon9he.jar for my xml to pdf conversion using xslt and xsl-fo, i am getting the exception that Invalid factory configuration
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet.
My lib folder contains the saxon9he.jar for xpdl to xml conversion using xslt2 and xalan.2.7.1.jar for xml to pdf converson.
The first part is working fine but the second part is getting exception due to saxon.jar's (trasnformer,transfor(arg1, arg2))presence is dominating the xalan.jar (transfor(a1,a2). But the second part of xml to pdf conversion (xalan.jar) is working fine if i removed the saxon9he.jar from my lib folder.
i am anticipating the good respomse from experts. plz find my sample code below.
thnx in advance...

```
out = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
        BufferedOutputStream    out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        Fop fop =   newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out1);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); 
        Source src = new StreamSource(fo);

        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        // i am getting exception at following line.
        transformer.transform(src, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Saxon and Xalan in the same application, then don't rely on TransformerFactory.newInstance(), which loads the first XSLT engine it finds. You can always load the one you want explicitly by instantiating its specific implementation of the TransformerFactory interface.